# Как получить токен ВК запрашивая через API Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, requests, token

День добрый.
Через Pycharm пишу простой код для API VK

```
class class_name():
  def __init__(self):
    
    self.user_token : str
    self.urlAuthorize = "http://oauth.vk.com/authorize/"


    self.params = {
      "client_id" : "9999999",
      "scope" : "messages.photos.friends.stories.pages.groups",
      "response_type" : "token",
      "display" : "page",
      "redirect_url": "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html",
      "v" : "5.131"
    }
```

Если URL

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize/?client_id=9999999&scope=messages.photos.friends.stories.pages.groups&response_type=token&display=page&v=5.131
```

вставить в адресную строку браузера, получаю токен

```
access_token=vk1.a.3l8RM2uTo-yygdLudcdhFXKqyd2Lwqhh79o.......
```

Если URL вставить в
`requests.get("""URL""")`
или
`requests.request("GET","URL")`
В консоли вижу код `<Response [200]>` , получаю страницу для авторизации пользователя.

Как получить токен?
Или как пройти этап авторизации и редиректа?

```
  def autorisation(self):
    var_requests = requests.get(url=self.urlAuthorize, params=self.params, headers=self.header)
   return  var_requests
```

Comment: А можно весь код?

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, одну строку только не указал, ну три. Добавил в пост.
В headers просто логин и пароль, так как в params толку нет от логина с паролем

Answer (score 0):

Получил токен через модуль `vk_api`, на этапе прохождения авторизации. Только пришлось добавить код

```
def auth_handler():
    """ При двухфакторной аутентификации вызывается эта функция.
    """

    # Код двухфакторной аутентификации
    key = input("Enter authentication code: ")
    # Если: True - сохранить, False - не сохранять.
    remember_device = True

    return key, remember_device


def mainAutor(login, password):
    """ Пример обработки двухфакторной аутентификации """
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
        login, password,
        # функция для обработки двухфакторной аутентификации
        auth_handler=auth_handler
    )

    try:
        vk_session.auth()
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return
```